# (django) error while overriding save() - name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to override the method `save()` of *my model*:

```
class Article(models.Model):
  number = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk: #means: if objects wasn't saved before
      self.number = Article.objects.count() +1 #number is 1-based
    super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now I tried to add a new article from the admin page. The error I get:

```
self.number = Article.objects.count() +1
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

***What am I doing wrong?***

---

## Some optional information:

- `number` is some kind of `ID`, to order the objects in my way but these `ID`s shouldn't be changed manually
- `number` is not allowed to be empty or blank, so I have to set a value before saving the first time (that's what I'm trying with that code snippet)
- When an object is saved, the default `number` should be equal to the number of all objects (after saving), in 1-based counting
- to change the order of the objects admin actions will be used

---

## The whole traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 544, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 211, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1509, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1449, in changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1007, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "/media/[directory to my projects]/projects_actual/myproject/myapp/models.py", line 69, in save
    seĺf.number = Article.objects.count() + 1
NameError: name 'seĺf' is not defined
[16/Apr/2017 11:07:00] "POST /admin/myapp/article/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 121043
```

---

Do you miss some information?

Comment: Kindly add the complete error traceback.

Comment: Traceback says there is letter `ĺ` not `l` in word `self`. Is it typo in your code?

Comment: Yes, it was. Thank you!